# pygame_sdl2 - app is crashing on mobile during pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

Tags: android, python, pygame, sdl-2

I am developing a game for android with [`pygame`](http://pygame.org/news) and [`pygame_sdl2`](https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2), and [`rapt`](https://github.com/renpy/rapt) for deploy.

Currently, the game is at a very first stage of development.

I have a joypad draw in the bottom left of my screen, and, when the mouse is pressed in the coordinates of the joypad's buttons, a character is moved according to the button durection. The mouse events are used as touch events as [in this (working) example](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example).

The problem is: the game is working on my laptop (I am using Ubuntu), but not on my mobile device. When I start the game, everything shows up as expected, but as soon as I touh the screen (no matter if it's on the buttons or somewhere else), the app goes in background.

My game is in a public github repo if you want to see the whole code (everything relevant is in the [`main.py`](https://github.com/umbe1987/android_platformer/blob/master/game/main.py) file).

I think the error is triggered by the call to [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed).

Here is some relevant code which hopefully would help in understanding the problem.

**Joypad class (btn_pressed method)**

```
def btn_pressed(self, mouse_event):
    # check if left mouse is being pressed
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        x, y  = mouse_event.pos
        if self.btn_up.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
            return 'UP'
        elif self.btn_down.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
            return 'DOWN'
        elif self.btn_left.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
            return 'LEFT'
        elif self.btn_right.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
            return 'RIGHT'
```

**Character class (move method)**

```
def move(self, joypad_direction):
    """
    move the character
    to be used along with Joypad.btn_pressed returns
    ('UP', 'DOWN' 'LEFT', 'RIGHT')
    """

    self.dx = 0
    self.dy = 0

    # check for horizontal move
    if joypad_direction == 'LEFT':
        self.dx = -self.speed
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
    if joypad_direction == 'RIGHT':
        self.dx = +self.speed
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

    self.dx = 0

    # check for vertical move
    if joypad_direction == 'UP':
        self.dy = -self.speed
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)
    if joypad_direction == 'DOWN':
        self.dy = +self.speed
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
        self.dy = 0
```

**main loop**

```
while True:

    ev = pygame.event.wait()

    # If not sleeping, draw the screen.
    if not sleeping:
        hero.move(joypad.btn_pressed(ev))
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 255))

        joypad.buttons.draw(screen)

        if x is not None:
            screen.blit(hero.image, (x, y))

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Maybe I found an issue in my code. In Joypad.btn_pressed() method I am passing an event, but that can be of any type (not just a (broadly speaking) "mouse event"). So the call to `ev.pos` may fail if (e.g.) the event is QUIT (which does not have a `pos` attribute). I am checking this now in my main loop by doing `if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION or ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:` before the call to `hero.move(joypad.btn_pressed(ev))`. I'll have to test on mobile one of these nights to see if this fixed the problem. Will come back with my test.

Comment: Are you sure you can deploy to desktop using these tools? I think that there may be some complications with the event handling. However, that fix seems needed and could be causing the issue. I will be interested to see if it will fix the problem.

Comment: It did indeed. I committed the fix to my repo (see above). It's working on both desktop and mobile so far, with some issue still to be fixed for the touch. I'll post the updated code part as answer when I'll be not from mobile. Thanks!

Comment: About deploying to desktop. I guess you can. I am just testing to mobile with rapt, but as long as the code is working much the same way on desktop (which is where I am developing from) it should be deployable. I am just treating the mouse events like the touch (although they act a bit differently). Feel free to look at my repo on github (https://github.com/umbe1987/android_platformer). It's at its very first stages but it coukd give some hints hopefully.

Comment: Does the initial problem persist after testing on mobile?

Comment: No, it's working now

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question to let people know that this question has an answer and that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, there was an issue in my main loop.

I simply had to change my code from:

```
if not sleeping:
    if not sleeping:
        hero.move(joypad.btn_pressed(ev))
```

to:

```
if not sleeping:
    if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION or ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        hero.move(joypad.btn_pressed(ev))
```

so that "Joypad class (btn_pressed method)" does not get an error when calling `x, y  = mouse_event.pos` when the event was (e.g.) QUIT, thus not returning any coordinates (see also the image belowe taken from the [pygame's event documentation page](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)).

[image]